# Android Studio Kotlin gradle proxy doesn't work on physical device

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, proxy, squid

So I need to run my app behind a proxy, I do set up one using Squid and it works great, I did check the proxy both from pc and my phone, no problem.
My gradle proxy setting looks like this:

- This is gradle.properties(Project Properties):

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=x.x.x.x
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.https.proxyHost=x.x.x.x
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128
```

- This is gradle.properties(Global Properties):

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=x.x.x.x
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.https.proxyHost=x.x.x.x
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128
```

- I also tried to put proxy on File>Appearance & Behavior>System Settings>HPPT Proxy
  [image: HPPT Proxy]

The weird thing is my app works just fine on Android Studio Emulator but when I try to debug on a physical device, proxy doesn't work, app can still run if I connect to company network. I have try on different devices, same thing happens.

I'm using `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2 with gradle 8.2`

Comment: I think there has been something broken in an android update - I use a proxy via wifi and *any* port value set results in requests going to port 80 on the proxy. This has only happened after one of the last 2 security updates